# creact-react-app ignores .gitignore in github

Tags: git, github, create-react-app

I'm new to React I'm using the command line util create-react-app https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app, to create a new boilerplate. When I create a new repository, commit, and push the boiler application I can't see my src folder. Is there a reason why this is happening?

.gitignore

```
# See https://help.github.com/ignore-files/ for more about ignoring files.

# dependencies
/node_modules

# testing
/coverage

# production
/build

# misc
.DS_Store
.env.local
.env.development.local
.env.test.local
.env.production.local

npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line did it for me

```
 git add --force react-app/ignore/
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `git add .` in the same directory that contains your `.git` directory, i.e., the root directory of the project, ahead of running `git commit`? This is what actually adds the files to your commit

Comment: I did, same issue src folder is still ignored

Comment: Are you getting any messages when you add/commit/push? What do you see when you run `git status`?

Comment: After running `create-react-app`  and getting into the project directory, running `git init && git add . && git status` I get the list of files tracked (which includes the src directory)... The only thing I could really imagine is that the `src` dir wouldn't be tracked if it were empty...